# How to use Git with submodules in a sneakernet environment?

Tags: git

I have a git environment that contains several modules and sub modules.

I want to be able to work on the project over "sneakernet" (between computers that don't have shared network).

from what I understood, [git bundle](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) does (almost) exactly what I want.

The problem that remains, is that if even if I clone a project, and it's sub-modules to a new computer, the remote links in the project will remain the links from the original computer.

Is there a solution that will also update the links to the new environment?

Comment: why do you have remote links and where are they supposed to point to when there is no network?

Comment: Each module has links to the submodules on the same machine.

Comment: did you try using relative paths?